# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getNativeVersion()Ljava/lang/String; Sigar

Tags: unsatisfiedlinkerror, sigar

Exception while instantiating Sigar

The problem exists on Redhat linux enterprise x86_64

Comment: I've got the same error but in winnt, I just add the comment to easy track this question, I'll also update with any findings on this matter.

Comment: On Redhat linux with JBoss server adding sigar jar to the LDPATH has resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Redhat linux with JBoss server adding sigar jar to the LDPATH has resolve the problem.